# How to parse double tilde(~~) file in HIVE

Tags: hive

I am trying to parse double tilde file to Hive. How to specify **row format delimited** to parse double tilde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multi delimiter SerDe

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe

E.g.

```
create external table mytable 
(
    i int
   ,j int
   ,k int
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("field.delim"="~~")
location ...
;
```